# Swiftでメソッドの実装をiOSバージョンごとに分ける・無くす方法

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

お世話になります。

iOS10と9に対応したいアプリの通知処理を作っています。
iOS9ではフォアグラウンドのとき通知が表示されないので通知の受信を

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification)
```

を使って制御してバックグラウンドと同じような通知を表示しようとしています。
しかしこれは**Deprecated**なメソッドだそうでiOS9のみで実装するようにしたいです。

```
@available(iOS 10.0より古い, *)
```

といった感じの指定がしたいのですがそういった事はできるのでしょうか？

---

修正
現状はメソッドの中でバージョンを判定して処理を分けるようにしました。

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
```

を実装している状態でiOS9ではフォアグラウンドで通知が来た時とバックグラウンドで通知表示を押して戻った時、
iOS10ではフォアグラウンド、バックグラウンド時の通知表示をタップした時、

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification)
```

が呼ばれ、これはiOS9でしか使う予定がないのでこの下のメソッドをiOS10より前でのみこの内容で実装するということは出来ないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな指定ができます。

```
@available(iOS, deprecated: 10.0)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {
    //...
}
```

他のプラットフォーム(tvOS, macOS等)もサポートする必要があれば、同様の複数のアトリビュートを重ねることもできます。

`@available`アトリビュートの使い方については、こちらに記載されているのですが、実例が少ないのでちょっとわかりにくいかもしれません。

[Declaration Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-ID348) ([The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097))

Comment: ありがとうございます。これはコードを書く人に非推奨を伝えるための属性ということでしょうか。`@available(iOS, deprecated: 10.0)`を指定してもコードが実行されてしまいました。質問がわかりにくいものでしたらすみません。

Comment: と言うよりはコンパイラのavailabilityチェックを通すためのもの、と言った方が良いでしょう。上記のアトリビュートを設定しないで、`UILocalNotification`のようにiOS10でdeprecatedになったクラスやメソッドを使用すると警告が表示されますが、その警告を抑止するためのアトリビュート(あるいは間違えてiOS10未満の指定がないところで使ったら警告を出させるためのアトリビュート、とも言えます)です。(警告を出すのはコードを書く人に非推奨を伝えるためですから、その通りと言っても良いのかもしれません。)処理そのものをバージョンによって書き分けたい場合には`if #available`構文を使用することになります。deprecatedになっても、その機能をサポートするコードがすぐに廃止されてしまうわけではないので、アトリビュートを付けただけでiOS10以降ではそのメソッドが呼ばれないようにする、と言ったアトリビュートはありません。

Comment: 確かにコンパイルした後にできるファイルはiOS10でもiOS9でも同じものを使っているようですからアトリビュートは環境ごとに**コードを分ける**ために使うわけではないのですね。あくまでも**コードの実行を制御する**ためのもので、コード自体はどの環境でも存在してしまうわけで、それがコードを書いている人にもわかるような形で表示されているということですね。曖昧なところが少しはっきりしてきました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`UIDevice`クラスを使います。

```
UIDevice.current.systemVersion
```

返り値は、数値でなく、文字列（`String`）なのに注意してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification)`はiOS9でも10でも呼ばれてしまうのでその中で分岐するように今回はこの方法でいくことにしました。コード内ではなく定義するところで過去のバージョンに関する実装を指定するのは難しそうですね。